# Split an ndarray using indices and offsets - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two `ndarray` objects `a` and `b`.

I want to **split** `b` using the **indices** provided in array `a`, but not in the traditional way (using `numpy.split`).

Specifically, I want to create **multiple subarrays** that start in indices of array `b`, call them `b[i]` and end in `b[i] + X`, where X is a number of my choosing.

**Example:**

`a = [1, 4, 9]`

`b = [30, 45, 10, 20, 5, 32, 104, 39, 23, 450, 2, 102, 50]`

My `split()` function would result in the following for `X=2`:

`[[45, 10, 20], [5, 32, 104], [450, 2, 102]]`

I have looked around in numpy but haven't found a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use slices, it works the same if you use Python lists instead of NumPy Arrays:

```
a = np.array([1, 4, 9])
b = np.array([30, 45, 10, 20, 5, 32, 104, 39, 23, 450, 2, 102, 50])

X = 3 # Add one extra here

print(np.array([b[i:i+X] for i in a]))
```

That will print:

```
[[ 45  10  20]
 [  5  32 104]
 [450   2 102]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach upon creating all those indices in a broadcasted manner with a range array extending the length of `X` -

```
b[a[:,None] + range(X+1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [369]: a = np.array([1, 4, 9])
     ...: b = np.array([30, 45, 10, 20, 5, 32, 104, 39, 23, 450, 2, 102, 50])
     ...: X = 2
     ...: 

# All needed indices generated    
In [375]: a[:,None] + range(X+1)
Out[375]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])

# Index into b to get those values
In [376]: b[a[:,None] + range(X+1)]
Out[376]: 
array([[ 45,  10,  20],
       [  5,  32, 104],
       [450,   2, 102]])
```

It creates those needed multiple subarrays as rows of a `2D` array.

If you need those as a list -

```
In [372]: b[a[:,None] + range(X+1)].tolist()
Out[372]: [[45, 10, 20], [5, 32, 104], [450, 2, 102]]
```